# Camel Beans - dynamic email subject

Tags: xslt, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Hi i have configured camel.xml file in activemq to send mail. Here is the xml config code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring                                                   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:properties"/>

<route>
  <description>Event Detected</description>
  <from uri="activemq:topic:Events?selector=JMSType='Event'"/>
  <to uri="xslt:file:{{activemq.conf}}/XLSs/Event.xsl"/>
  <to uri="smtp://mail.net:25?from=abc@abc.com&amp;to=abc@abc.com&amp;subject= Hello World!&amp;contentType=text/html"/>
</route>
</camelContext>
</bean>
</beans>
```

And here is the Event.xslt that i used to transform the xml into html to be sent in the mail body.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet   version="1.0"                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Event">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Event Detected!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>
      Event Detected!
    </h2>       
    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>       
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way i can dynamically set the email subject to the Title property from the message body ?

Here is my xml as well

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Event xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Title>Test</Title>  
 </Event>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xpath to extract the title from the messge body, and set as a header with the name Subject. Then the mail component will use the value from the header as the email subject.

Something a long the lines of

```
<setHeader headerName="Subject">
  <xpath>/Event/Title/text()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

Mind that xpath can be tricky, and especially if your xml uses namespaces. If that is the case then the xpath expression must use namespace mappings too.

See more details at

- http://camel.apache.org/xpath

Comment: Hi  @clausibsen It works fine when i declare a string as a constant in the setHeader tag                                                                           <setHeader headerName="Subject">
  <constant>Test</constant>
</setHeader>     However when i specify my xpath the mail component is itself not working.

Comment: I have also added the xml part in my question.

Comment: Its working fine. I had to declare <setHeader> tag before the to uri tag pointing to my xslt. Thanks  a lot !!!